# Prolog Reciprocal Counting

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to get Prolog to compute a reciprocal.

I want to ask Prolog this question:  rec/2 like so rec(3, Result).

The formula i try to convert is this

```
f(n) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 ... + 1/n
```

It should lead to 1.833333...

I have `rec(0,0).` at the start which gives me 0 if my input is 0.

How should I phrase my clauses to avoid a dividing by zero exception?

So far I know I have to go over it with recursion.

I tried:

```
rec(N, R):-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    rec(N1, R1),
```

I don't know how to approach the problem after that because everything I tried wouldn´t give me decimal numbers yet the right solution, most of the time I get the divide by zero failure cause of the `rec(0,0).` definition.

Comment: Firstly, it looks like you left a line out of your code. I don't see a division operation going on. Secondly, `rec(0, 0)` would not be valid since `f(n)` is only defined for `n > 0`, right? Your base case should be `rec(1, 1).` then your recursive case would be for `N > 1`.

Comment: Ok i changed it rec(1,1) for the base case. But how should i write the arithmetic operation? The ways i tested it, it always rewrites my first Value. Via trace i got like: 
1/1   //base case
1/2 = 0,5
and then it does 0,5/3

Comment: OK never mind i got it.

Thanks for the help :D (i hate it that enter instantly posts...)

Comment: You do not give the relationship between `R` and `R1` in your clause.